# how to open file with specific extension in fileDialogue

Tags: java, openfiledialog, filedialog

I am trying to Open a file with specific extension ( .fcg or .wtg ) using file Dialog
is there a way to do it ??

Answer (score 2):

If you can use `JFileChooser` you can use `JFileChooser.addChoosableFileFilter()` to filter files by extension.

```
    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    fileChooser.addChoosableFileFilter(new FileFilter() {

        @Override
        public String getDescription() {
            return "*.fct, *.wtg";
        }

        @Override
        public boolean accept(File f) {
            return f.getName().endsWith(".fcg") ||
            f.getName().endsWith(".wtg");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, I will have to use JFileChooser if i could not do it using fileDialog

Answer (score 1):

You can use this this code to choose a file and read

```
public void openFile() throws Exception {
    int rowCount = 0;
    int rowNo = 2;
    String id = "";
    String name = "";
    JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
    int result = fc.showOpenDialog(new JPanel());
    if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        String file = String.valueOf(fc.getSelectedFile());

        File fil = new File(file);
        System.out.println("File Selected" + file);
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(fil);
        int ch;
        while ((ch = fin.read()) != -1) {
            System.out.print((char)ch);
        }
    } else {
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question.  BTW - what is the empty `else` statement intended to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

As this is google search #1 for me, this is the solution which worked best for me:

[How to restrict file choosers in java to specific files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18575655/how-to-restrict-file-choosers-in-java-to-specific-files)

specifics:

```
    JFileChooser open = new JFileChooser(openPath);
    FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("PLSQL Files", "sql", "prc", "fnc", "pks"
                                                                    , "pkb", "trg", "vw", "tps" , "tpb");
    open.setFileFilter(filter);
```